# How to split json in to 3 parts on the basis of key using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried ...

Data:

```
var myJSON = {
    "QA": "02",
    "nums": "1",
    "QB": [
        {
            "AV1": {
                "pr": "04",
                "sac": "04",
                "av": "01",
                "bud": "01",
                "stk": "01",
                "mtl": "01"
            }
        }
    ],
    "numbers": "1",
    "Q1toQ5": [
        {
            "str": "1",
            "me": "a",
            "gr": "01",
            "bge": "25",
            "dbo": "1/1/1990",
            "mtl": "",
            "id": "04",
            "ed": "08",
            "wy": "05"
        },
        {
            "ocwe": "qa",
            "totmem": "6",
            "tot2yr": "0"
        }
    ],
    "Q6": {
        "elect": "01",
        "ac": "01",
        "cjv": "02",
        "cf": "02",
        "ctv": "02",
        "ls": "02",
        "pcl": "02",
        "rtr": "02",
        "tw": "02",
        "wm": "02",
        "agri": "01",
        "nod": "3"
    },
    "Q7": "01",
    "Q8": "01",
    "Q9": "01",
    "Q10": "04",
    "Q11": [
        {
            "AV1": {
                "yq": "06",
                "ttv": "01",
                "avor": "02",
                "son": "01",
                "fs": "02",
                "toc": "01",
                "tsrc": "04",
                "dvpv": "02"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Q12": [
        {
            "mt": "05",
            "ol": "08,12"
        }
    ],
    "Q13": "09"
};
```

Javascript:

```
var part1 = [];
var part2 = [];
var part3 = [];
var i = 0;
var obj = myJSON;

for (var key in obj) {
    if (i < 4) {
        part1.push(key, obj[key]);
    }
    else if (i < 8) {
        part2.push(key, obj[key]);
    }
    else {
        part3.push(key, obj[key]);
    }

    i++;
}

var Part1 = JSON.stringify(part1);
var Part2 = JSON.stringify(part2);
var Part3 = JSON.stringify(part3);
```

When I check the result it was not as per expected json.

Please suggest

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object initializer. When you're writing it literally in JavaScript code, it's never JSON (unless it's in a string literal).

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over your json object and get the key value pairs -

```
var result = $.parseJSON(myJSON);
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
//your logic
    if (i < 4) {
        part1.push(v);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must prettify this json object and then use forEach for iterate , its more useful to get i as increament value